# Displaying Analytics on Website

Tags: google-analytics, google-api-js-client

I am trying to add a page to a website that displays the analytics from a gapi analytics account. I have a google analytics account already, and have created a google service account to allow authentication without google sign in. After creating the account I was given a json key which contains the following information:

```
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": ".....",
"private_key_id": "....",
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email": "......",
"client_id": "......",
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_x509_cert_url"...."
```

Then I am atempting to authenticate the sign in using:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({

 'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': token
       }

 });
```

Does anyone know how I find the access token? Because it was not given in the json file with the other information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the first port of call would be the documentation, which has an example for [Embed API Server-side Authorization](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) (yes, this is a link-only answer, but if Google goes offline the OP is screwed in any case).

The example is in Python, however the same technique works with all the client libraries.

Comment: Yes I have already looked at that. I am was working in java script though. Also when I tried to install pip using the comand

   " sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client "

On my console it did not work for me

Comment: If you could access the private key via client side code it would not actually be private. You need a serverside script (or an interactive login by an authorized user) to generate the token.